# Do background js scripts run on a different thread in Chrome OS apps?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-app, google-chrome-os

On the manifest for Chrome OS apps one must declare background js scripts.

```
{
  "name": "Hello World!",
  "description": "My first Chrome App.",
  "version": "0.1",
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "app": {
    "background": {
      "scripts": ["background.js"]
    }
  },
  "icons": { "16": "calculator-16.png", "128": "calculator-128.png" }
}
```

Are each of these running in their own thread?

Do they block each other or the JS threads running on the app windows?

Comment: This is  simply a shorthand for multiple script tags in html. There is only one background page. Also, JavaScript is single threaded.

Comment: JS is single threaded yes (unless using workers) but browser windows have their own thread. In any case I'd like to see a source to confirm.

Comment: Internal implementation of browser windows is irrelevant. The JS engine that runs a page script is single threaded. It's just the way it always was, and is.

Comment: As for confirmation, you can see it yourself by inspecting the extension's background page in devtools or in the [documentation](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/background_pages): "A background page will be generated by the extension system that includes each of the files listed in the scripts property."

Comment: Ok, and what about the other windows of the application? Do these run on the same thread as the background page?

Comment: All extension's own pages run in the same *process*. You can see it in Chrome Task Manager. Content scripts run in the page *process*, as well any code code injected into the web page from a content script, of course.

Comment: As for threading, it is not used for normal (non-worker) javascript at all. I don't have a "proof" at hand, but that's just the way it has always been.

Comment: By default Chrome assigns a new process to each tab/window unless these are from the same site which is why I'm asking. https://blog.chromium.org/2009/12/links-that-open-in-new-processes.html

Comment: Yes, and since the extension's own pages all have the same origin of `chrome-extension://***id***` they run in the same process as you can see in Chrome Task Manager. The background page is just another page with that same origin.

Comment: Thanks for your input. If you put this information in an answer I will accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Chrome App windows are only "views", and are not living in separate processes. Here's the proof. Each app view page can run `chrome.runtime.getBackgroundPage` to get a direct reference to the background page's javascript context (all variables, functions, etc). Also the background page can get references to the javascript contexts of the app windows, using `chrome.app.window.getAll` to reference `contentWindow` on the appWindow objects returned.

As another commenter points out, the situation is a bit different for chrome extensions, but since the question is about apps, we only concern ourselves with that.